# Example of Devil's nested radicals

Tags: recreational-mathematics, nested-radicals, constants

Let the following nested radical :

$$\sqrt{665+2x}=x$$

There is a hidden quadratic equation and the result is :

$$x=\sqrt{666}+1$$

So we see the number $666$ appear .

### My question :

Do you know (more or less trivial) nested radical where the devil's number appear ?

Can we build it as in my example ?

Thanks in advance and have fun .

Ps: I don't speak about Galois's theory .

Comment: The general approach to solve such equations is repeated using "squaring both sides" (here squaring once is sufficient). This might give solutions that do not satisfy the original equation, but you cannot "lose" solutions. You just have to check which of the solutions do the job.

Comment: $x=1+\sqrt{666}$ is the only real solution of $x=\sqrt{666+3+\frac{2(666-1)}{x}}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wrote a small program looking for equations of the form $ax^2 + 2bx + c = 0$ and found these quadratic equations below. Their roots all contain the number $\sqrt {666}$.

My program requires that $|b| \le 20$ and $|a| \le 700,\ |c| \le 700$.
Of course these limits can be extended.

By the way, your equation happens be to number 66 in the list below.

Equations 64 and 68 also look interesting to me since their solutions don't have a denominator.

```
Equation (1):  ( -266 ) * (x**2) + ( -40 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (1):  [-10/133 + 3*sqrt(74)/266, -3*sqrt(74)/266 - 10/133]

Equation (2):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -40 ) * x + ( -266)  = 0
Solutions (2):  [20 - 3*sqrt(74), 20 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (3):  ( -133 ) * (x**2) + ( -40 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (3):  [-20/133 + 3*sqrt(74)/133, -3*sqrt(74)/133 - 20/133]

Equation (4):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + ( -40 ) * x + ( -133)  = 0
Solutions (4):  [10 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 10 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (5):  ( -305 ) * (x**2) + ( -38 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (5):  [-19/305 + 3*sqrt(74)/305, -3*sqrt(74)/305 - 19/305]

Equation (6):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -38 ) * x + ( -305)  = 0
Solutions (6):  [19 - 3*sqrt(74), 19 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (7):  ( -342 ) * (x**2) + ( -36 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (7):  [-1/19 + sqrt(74)/114, -sqrt(74)/114 - 1/19]

Equation (8):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -36 ) * x + ( -342)  = 0
Solutions (8):  [18 - 3*sqrt(74), 18 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (9):  ( -171 ) * (x**2) + ( -36 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (9):  [-2/19 + sqrt(74)/57, -sqrt(74)/57 - 2/19]

Equation (10):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + ( -36 ) * x + ( -171)  = 0
Solutions (10):  [9 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 9 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (11):  ( -114 ) * (x**2) + ( -36 ) * x + (   3)  = 0
Solutions (11):  [-3/19 + sqrt(74)/38, -sqrt(74)/38 - 3/19]

Equation (12):  (   3 ) * (x**2) + ( -36 ) * x + ( -114)  = 0
Solutions (12):  [6 - sqrt(74), 6 + sqrt(74)]

Equation (13):  ( -377 ) * (x**2) + ( -34 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (13):  [-17/377 + 3*sqrt(74)/377, -3*sqrt(74)/377 - 17/377]

Equation (14):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -34 ) * x + ( -377)  = 0
Solutions (14):  [17 - 3*sqrt(74), 17 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (15):  ( -410 ) * (x**2) + ( -32 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (15):  [-8/205 + 3*sqrt(74)/410, -3*sqrt(74)/410 - 8/205]

Equation (16):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -32 ) * x + ( -410)  = 0
Solutions (16):  [16 - 3*sqrt(74), 16 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (17):  ( -205 ) * (x**2) + ( -32 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (17):  [-16/205 + 3*sqrt(74)/205, -3*sqrt(74)/205 - 16/205]

Equation (18):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + ( -32 ) * x + ( -205)  = 0
Solutions (18):  [8 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 8 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (19):  ( -441 ) * (x**2) + ( -30 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (19):  [-5/147 + sqrt(74)/147, -sqrt(74)/147 - 5/147]

Equation (20):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -30 ) * x + ( -441)  = 0
Solutions (20):  [15 - 3*sqrt(74), 15 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (21):  ( -147 ) * (x**2) + ( -30 ) * x + (   3)  = 0
Solutions (21):  [-5/49 + sqrt(74)/49, -sqrt(74)/49 - 5/49]

Equation (22):  (   3 ) * (x**2) + ( -30 ) * x + ( -147)  = 0
Solutions (22):  [5 - sqrt(74), 5 + sqrt(74)]

Equation (23):  ( -470 ) * (x**2) + ( -28 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (23):  [-7/235 + 3*sqrt(74)/470, -3*sqrt(74)/470 - 7/235]

Equation (24):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -28 ) * x + ( -470)  = 0
Solutions (24):  [14 - 3*sqrt(74), 14 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (25):  ( -235 ) * (x**2) + ( -28 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (25):  [-14/235 + 3*sqrt(74)/235, -3*sqrt(74)/235 - 14/235]

Equation (26):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + ( -28 ) * x + ( -235)  = 0
Solutions (26):  [7 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 7 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (27):  ( -497 ) * (x**2) + ( -26 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (27):  [-13/497 + 3*sqrt(74)/497, -3*sqrt(74)/497 - 13/497]

Equation (28):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -26 ) * x + ( -497)  = 0
Solutions (28):  [13 - 3*sqrt(74), 13 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (29):  ( -522 ) * (x**2) + ( -24 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (29):  [-2/87 + sqrt(74)/174, -sqrt(74)/174 - 2/87]

Equation (30):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -24 ) * x + ( -522)  = 0
Solutions (30):  [12 - 3*sqrt(74), 12 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (31):  ( -261 ) * (x**2) + ( -24 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (31):  [-4/87 + sqrt(74)/87, -sqrt(74)/87 - 4/87]

Equation (32):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + ( -24 ) * x + ( -261)  = 0
Solutions (32):  [6 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 6 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (33):  ( -174 ) * (x**2) + ( -24 ) * x + (   3)  = 0
Solutions (33):  [-2/29 + sqrt(74)/58, -sqrt(74)/58 - 2/29]

Equation (34):  (   3 ) * (x**2) + ( -24 ) * x + ( -174)  = 0
Solutions (34):  [4 - sqrt(74), 4 + sqrt(74)]

Equation (35):  ( -545 ) * (x**2) + ( -22 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (35):  [-11/545 + 3*sqrt(74)/545, -3*sqrt(74)/545 - 11/545]

Equation (36):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -22 ) * x + ( -545)  = 0
Solutions (36):  [11 - 3*sqrt(74), 11 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (37):  ( -566 ) * (x**2) + ( -20 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (37):  [-5/283 + 3*sqrt(74)/566, -3*sqrt(74)/566 - 5/283]

Equation (38):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -20 ) * x + ( -566)  = 0
Solutions (38):  [10 - 3*sqrt(74), 10 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (39):  ( -283 ) * (x**2) + ( -20 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (39):  [-10/283 + 3*sqrt(74)/283, -3*sqrt(74)/283 - 10/283]

Equation (40):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + ( -20 ) * x + ( -283)  = 0
Solutions (40):  [5 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 5 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (41):  ( -585 ) * (x**2) + ( -18 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (41):  [-1/65 + sqrt(74)/195, -sqrt(74)/195 - 1/65]

Equation (42):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -18 ) * x + ( -585)  = 0
Solutions (42):  [9 - 3*sqrt(74), 9 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (43):  ( -195 ) * (x**2) + ( -18 ) * x + (   3)  = 0
Solutions (43):  [-3/65 + sqrt(74)/65, -sqrt(74)/65 - 3/65]

Equation (44):  (   3 ) * (x**2) + ( -18 ) * x + ( -195)  = 0
Solutions (44):  [3 - sqrt(74), 3 + sqrt(74)]

Equation (45):  ( -602 ) * (x**2) + ( -16 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (45):  [-4/301 + 3*sqrt(74)/602, -3*sqrt(74)/602 - 4/301]

Equation (46):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -16 ) * x + ( -602)  = 0
Solutions (46):  [8 - 3*sqrt(74), 8 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (47):  ( -301 ) * (x**2) + ( -16 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (47):  [-8/301 + 3*sqrt(74)/301, -3*sqrt(74)/301 - 8/301]

Equation (48):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + ( -16 ) * x + ( -301)  = 0
Solutions (48):  [4 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 4 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (49):  ( -617 ) * (x**2) + ( -14 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (49):  [-7/617 + 3*sqrt(74)/617, -3*sqrt(74)/617 - 7/617]

Equation (50):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -14 ) * x + ( -617)  = 0
Solutions (50):  [7 - 3*sqrt(74), 7 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (51):  ( -630 ) * (x**2) + ( -12 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (51):  [-1/105 + sqrt(74)/210, -sqrt(74)/210 - 1/105]

Equation (52):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -12 ) * x + ( -630)  = 0
Solutions (52):  [6 - 3*sqrt(74), 6 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (53):  ( -315 ) * (x**2) + ( -12 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (53):  [-2/105 + sqrt(74)/105, -sqrt(74)/105 - 2/105]

Equation (54):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + ( -12 ) * x + ( -315)  = 0
Solutions (54):  [3 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 3 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (55):  ( -641 ) * (x**2) + ( -10 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (55):  [-5/641 + 3*sqrt(74)/641, -3*sqrt(74)/641 - 5/641]

Equation (56):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + ( -10 ) * x + ( -641)  = 0
Solutions (56):  [5 - 3*sqrt(74), 5 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (57):  ( -650 ) * (x**2) + (  -8 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (57):  [-2/325 + 3*sqrt(74)/650, -3*sqrt(74)/650 - 2/325]

Equation (58):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  -8 ) * x + ( -650)  = 0
Solutions (58):  [4 - 3*sqrt(74), 4 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (59):  ( -325 ) * (x**2) + (  -8 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (59):  [-4/325 + 3*sqrt(74)/325, -3*sqrt(74)/325 - 4/325]

Equation (60):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  -8 ) * x + ( -325)  = 0
Solutions (60):  [2 - 3*sqrt(74)/2, 2 + 3*sqrt(74)/2]

Equation (61):  ( -657 ) * (x**2) + (  -6 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (61):  [-1/219 + sqrt(74)/219, -sqrt(74)/219 - 1/219]

Equation (62):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  -6 ) * x + ( -657)  = 0
Solutions (62):  [3 - 3*sqrt(74), 3 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (63):  ( -662 ) * (x**2) + (  -4 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (63):  [-1/331 + 3*sqrt(74)/662, -3*sqrt(74)/662 - 1/331]

Equation (64):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  -4 ) * x + ( -662)  = 0
Solutions (64):  [2 - 3*sqrt(74), 2 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (65):  ( -665 ) * (x**2) + (  -2 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (65):  [-1/665 + 3*sqrt(74)/665, -3*sqrt(74)/665 - 1/665]

Equation (66):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  -2 ) * x + ( -665)  = 0
Solutions (66):  [1 - 3*sqrt(74), 1 + 3*sqrt(74)]

Equation (67):  ( -665 ) * (x**2) + (   2 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (67):  [1/665 - 3*sqrt(74)/665, 1/665 + 3*sqrt(74)/665]

Equation (68):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (   2 ) * x + ( -665)  = 0
Solutions (68):  [-1 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 1]

Equation (69):  ( -662 ) * (x**2) + (   4 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (69):  [1/331 - 3*sqrt(74)/662, 1/331 + 3*sqrt(74)/662]

Equation (70):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (   4 ) * x + ( -662)  = 0
Solutions (70):  [-2 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 2]

Equation (71):  ( -657 ) * (x**2) + (   6 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (71):  [1/219 - sqrt(74)/219, 1/219 + sqrt(74)/219]

Equation (72):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (   6 ) * x + ( -657)  = 0
Solutions (72):  [-3 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 3]

Equation (73):  ( -650 ) * (x**2) + (   8 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (73):  [2/325 - 3*sqrt(74)/650, 2/325 + 3*sqrt(74)/650]

Equation (74):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (   8 ) * x + ( -650)  = 0
Solutions (74):  [-4 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 4]

Equation (75):  ( -325 ) * (x**2) + (   8 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (75):  [4/325 - 3*sqrt(74)/325, 4/325 + 3*sqrt(74)/325]

Equation (76):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (   8 ) * x + ( -325)  = 0
Solutions (76):  [-2 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 2]

Equation (77):  ( -641 ) * (x**2) + (  10 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (77):  [5/641 - 3*sqrt(74)/641, 5/641 + 3*sqrt(74)/641]

Equation (78):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  10 ) * x + ( -641)  = 0
Solutions (78):  [-5 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 5]

Equation (79):  ( -630 ) * (x**2) + (  12 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (79):  [1/105 - sqrt(74)/210, 1/105 + sqrt(74)/210]

Equation (80):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  12 ) * x + ( -630)  = 0
Solutions (80):  [-6 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 6]

Equation (81):  ( -315 ) * (x**2) + (  12 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (81):  [2/105 - sqrt(74)/105, 2/105 + sqrt(74)/105]

Equation (82):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  12 ) * x + ( -315)  = 0
Solutions (82):  [-3 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 3]

Equation (83):  ( -617 ) * (x**2) + (  14 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (83):  [7/617 - 3*sqrt(74)/617, 7/617 + 3*sqrt(74)/617]

Equation (84):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  14 ) * x + ( -617)  = 0
Solutions (84):  [-7 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 7]

Equation (85):  ( -602 ) * (x**2) + (  16 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (85):  [4/301 - 3*sqrt(74)/602, 4/301 + 3*sqrt(74)/602]

Equation (86):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  16 ) * x + ( -602)  = 0
Solutions (86):  [-8 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 8]

Equation (87):  ( -301 ) * (x**2) + (  16 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (87):  [8/301 - 3*sqrt(74)/301, 8/301 + 3*sqrt(74)/301]

Equation (88):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  16 ) * x + ( -301)  = 0
Solutions (88):  [-4 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 4]

Equation (89):  ( -585 ) * (x**2) + (  18 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (89):  [1/65 - sqrt(74)/195, 1/65 + sqrt(74)/195]

Equation (90):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  18 ) * x + ( -585)  = 0
Solutions (90):  [-9 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 9]

Equation (91):  ( -195 ) * (x**2) + (  18 ) * x + (   3)  = 0
Solutions (91):  [3/65 - sqrt(74)/65, 3/65 + sqrt(74)/65]

Equation (92):  (   3 ) * (x**2) + (  18 ) * x + ( -195)  = 0
Solutions (92):  [-3 + sqrt(74), -sqrt(74) - 3]

Equation (93):  ( -566 ) * (x**2) + (  20 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (93):  [5/283 - 3*sqrt(74)/566, 5/283 + 3*sqrt(74)/566]

Equation (94):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  20 ) * x + ( -566)  = 0
Solutions (94):  [-10 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 10]

Equation (95):  ( -283 ) * (x**2) + (  20 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (95):  [10/283 - 3*sqrt(74)/283, 10/283 + 3*sqrt(74)/283]

Equation (96):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  20 ) * x + ( -283)  = 0
Solutions (96):  [-5 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 5]

Equation (97):  ( -545 ) * (x**2) + (  22 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (97):  [11/545 - 3*sqrt(74)/545, 11/545 + 3*sqrt(74)/545]

Equation (98):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  22 ) * x + ( -545)  = 0
Solutions (98):  [-11 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 11]

Equation (99):  ( -522 ) * (x**2) + (  24 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (99):  [2/87 - sqrt(74)/174, 2/87 + sqrt(74)/174]

Equation (100):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  24 ) * x + ( -522)  = 0
Solutions (100):  [-12 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 12]

Equation (101):  ( -261 ) * (x**2) + (  24 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (101):  [4/87 - sqrt(74)/87, 4/87 + sqrt(74)/87]

Equation (102):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  24 ) * x + ( -261)  = 0
Solutions (102):  [-6 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 6]

Equation (103):  ( -174 ) * (x**2) + (  24 ) * x + (   3)  = 0
Solutions (103):  [2/29 - sqrt(74)/58, 2/29 + sqrt(74)/58]

Equation (104):  (   3 ) * (x**2) + (  24 ) * x + ( -174)  = 0
Solutions (104):  [-4 + sqrt(74), -sqrt(74) - 4]

Equation (105):  ( -497 ) * (x**2) + (  26 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (105):  [13/497 - 3*sqrt(74)/497, 13/497 + 3*sqrt(74)/497]

Equation (106):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  26 ) * x + ( -497)  = 0
Solutions (106):  [-13 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 13]

Equation (107):  ( -470 ) * (x**2) + (  28 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (107):  [7/235 - 3*sqrt(74)/470, 7/235 + 3*sqrt(74)/470]

Equation (108):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  28 ) * x + ( -470)  = 0
Solutions (108):  [-14 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 14]

Equation (109):  ( -235 ) * (x**2) + (  28 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (109):  [14/235 - 3*sqrt(74)/235, 14/235 + 3*sqrt(74)/235]

Equation (110):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  28 ) * x + ( -235)  = 0
Solutions (110):  [-7 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 7]

Equation (111):  ( -441 ) * (x**2) + (  30 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (111):  [5/147 - sqrt(74)/147, 5/147 + sqrt(74)/147]

Equation (112):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  30 ) * x + ( -441)  = 0
Solutions (112):  [-15 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 15]

Equation (113):  ( -147 ) * (x**2) + (  30 ) * x + (   3)  = 0
Solutions (113):  [5/49 - sqrt(74)/49, 5/49 + sqrt(74)/49]

Equation (114):  (   3 ) * (x**2) + (  30 ) * x + ( -147)  = 0
Solutions (114):  [-5 + sqrt(74), -sqrt(74) - 5]

Equation (115):  ( -410 ) * (x**2) + (  32 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (115):  [8/205 - 3*sqrt(74)/410, 8/205 + 3*sqrt(74)/410]

Equation (116):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  32 ) * x + ( -410)  = 0
Solutions (116):  [-16 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 16]

Equation (117):  ( -205 ) * (x**2) + (  32 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (117):  [16/205 - 3*sqrt(74)/205, 16/205 + 3*sqrt(74)/205]

Equation (118):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  32 ) * x + ( -205)  = 0
Solutions (118):  [-8 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 8]

Equation (119):  ( -377 ) * (x**2) + (  34 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (119):  [17/377 - 3*sqrt(74)/377, 17/377 + 3*sqrt(74)/377]

Equation (120):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  34 ) * x + ( -377)  = 0
Solutions (120):  [-17 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 17]

Equation (121):  ( -342 ) * (x**2) + (  36 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (121):  [1/19 - sqrt(74)/114, 1/19 + sqrt(74)/114]

Equation (122):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  36 ) * x + ( -342)  = 0
Solutions (122):  [-18 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 18]

Equation (123):  ( -171 ) * (x**2) + (  36 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (123):  [2/19 - sqrt(74)/57, 2/19 + sqrt(74)/57]

Equation (124):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  36 ) * x + ( -171)  = 0
Solutions (124):  [-9 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 9]

Equation (125):  ( -114 ) * (x**2) + (  36 ) * x + (   3)  = 0
Solutions (125):  [3/19 - sqrt(74)/38, 3/19 + sqrt(74)/38]

Equation (126):  (   3 ) * (x**2) + (  36 ) * x + ( -114)  = 0
Solutions (126):  [-6 + sqrt(74), -sqrt(74) - 6]

Equation (127):  ( -305 ) * (x**2) + (  38 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (127):  [19/305 - 3*sqrt(74)/305, 19/305 + 3*sqrt(74)/305]

Equation (128):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  38 ) * x + ( -305)  = 0
Solutions (128):  [-19 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 19]

Equation (129):  ( -266 ) * (x**2) + (  40 ) * x + (   1)  = 0
Solutions (129):  [10/133 - 3*sqrt(74)/266, 10/133 + 3*sqrt(74)/266]

Equation (130):  (   1 ) * (x**2) + (  40 ) * x + ( -266)  = 0
Solutions (130):  [-20 + 3*sqrt(74), -3*sqrt(74) - 20]

Equation (131):  ( -133 ) * (x**2) + (  40 ) * x + (   2)  = 0
Solutions (131):  [20/133 - 3*sqrt(74)/133, 20/133 + 3*sqrt(74)/133]

Equation (132):  (   2 ) * (x**2) + (  40 ) * x + ( -133)  = 0
Solutions (132):  [-10 + 3*sqrt(74)/2, -3*sqrt(74)/2 - 10]
```

In case anyone wants to play further with it, here is the Python code.

```
import math as mt
from sympy import Symbol
from sympy.core.sympify import sympify
from sympy.solvers import solve

MAX_B = 20

MAX_A = 700
MAX_C = 700

x = Symbol('x')
z = solve(x**2 - 1, x)

def is_int(a):
    return abs(a - mt.floor(a))<0.001

def generate_eq_str(a, b, c):
    return ("( % 3d" % a + " ) * (x**2) + "  + "( % 3d" % ( 2*b )  + " ) * x + " +  "( % 3d" % c + ")")

def main():
    ind = 1
    
    for b in range(-MAX_B, MAX_B+1):
        for c in range(1 + int(mt.floor(mt.sqrt(abs(b))))):
            if (c > 0):
                a = ( b**2-666 ) / c
                if (is_int(a)):
                    if (abs(a) <= MAX_A and abs(b) <= MAX_B and abs(c) <= MAX_C):
    
                        str1 = generate_eq_str(a, b, c)
                        print("Equation (%d): " % ind, str1, " = 0")
                        
                        eq = sympify(str1)
                        z = solve(eq, x)
                        print("Solutions (%d): " % ind, z)
                        print()
                        ind += 1
                        
    
                        str2 = generate_eq_str(c, b, a)
                        print("Equation (%d): " % ind, str2, " = 0")
                        
                        eq = sympify(str2)
                        z = solve(eq, x)
                        print("Solutions (%d): " % ind, z)
                        print()
                        ind += 1
    


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Setting aside the fact that ["the Number of the Beast" might be 616](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/616_(number)), or perhaps both 616 and 666 based on different spellings of "(Emperor) Nero", we can render 666 from an appropriate combination of the seemingly innocuous numbers 3 and 15:

$\sqrt{(15+\sqrt3)\sqrt3}$

To wit:

$\sqrt{(15+\sqrt3)\sqrt3}=\sqrt{(15\sqrt3)+\sqrt9}$

Then apply the identity

$\sqrt{a+\sqrt b}=\sqrt{(a+\sqrt{a^2-b})/2}+\sqrt{(a-\sqrt{a^2-b})/2}$

where here $a^2=675$ and $b=9$:

$\sqrt{(15+\sqrt3)\sqrt3}=\sqrt{(15\sqrt3+\sqrt{666})/2}+\sqrt{(15\sqrt3-\sqrt{666})/2}$.

The number 616 actually has this beat.  Start with just $2\sqrt7$ and use the same identity as above, with $25^2=625$:

$2\sqrt7=\sqrt{25+\sqrt9}=\sqrt{(25+\sqrt{616})/2}+\sqrt{(25-\sqrt{616})/2}$.